# Creating a link with HTML code

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

I have created a table inside my template, using the Mediawiki programming language as explained in the documentation. In the table cells are an image and a text. Now I would like to make the whole table clickable, so that it links to a different page. To do this I use the wiki syntax and define the page, where the user should get referred. Then using the Pipe-character, I set the table code instead of a standard text.

Unfortunately, only the table gets displayed, while the source code of the Link syntax gets print out as a text. Is there a fix you can recommend me?
Or at least something temporary?

Here is my wiki source code:

```
[[:Category:{{{1|}}} Products|
{|
|[[File:Apple.png|50px|left|link=]]
|Order our apples
|}]]
```

This should be the html code it should generate:

```
<a href="http://example.com/Category:Apple_Products">
<table>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <div class="floatleft">
                     <img src="http://example.com/Apple.png">
               </div>
           </td>
           <td>
                 Order our apples
           </td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</a>
```

(I also tried adding the following instead of the Link syntax:

```
<a href="http://example.com/</nowiki>{{#replace:{{{1|}}}| |_}}_Songs">
```

It did not work, because the parsing caused a conversion of ">" and "<" characters..

Comment: You probably meant `<nowiki/>` (with a trailing slash). I have tried several approaches: * subtemplating; * generating tables with the `<table>` tag; * generating tables with `#tag` -- all of these approaches break MediaWiki piped links. Also, `#tag: a` seems to be prohibited to generate `<a>`, as well as raw `<a>` is. Maybe it's worth trying to put links in the table cells? Say, `[[File:Apple.png|50px|left|link=:Category:{{{1|}}} Products]]` and `[[:Category:{{{1|}}} Products|Order our apples]]` respectively? (AFAIR, you can't put tables in links).

Comment: I don't understand, you're trying to create a wikilink whose label is actually a table with an image inside?